# Tp entity above head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make it when I hold an item a invisible ocelot summons above my head so no one can see it and it doesnt effect movement so when I hold the item near creepers it scares them away.

```
/tp @e[type=ocelot] WolfySocks
```

I have all the invisiblity down and no AI but it still moves me when I hold it so I'm trying to make it so it doesn't push me away. Any help is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The command `/tp` teleports something relative to itself, so for example `/tp @e[type=sheep] ~ ~2 ~` teleports every sheep two blocks up.

The command `/teleport` teleports something relative to the command executor, so for example `/teleport @e[type=sheep] ~ ~2 ~` teleports every sheep two blocks above you, so they all end up above your head, which is what you want.

Also I recommend you to use a tag on the ocelot to mark it as one that should be invisible and scare away creepers. To do that, you can either select it with some selector after spawning and add the tag to it:

`/scoreboard players tag @e[type=ocelot,<more selectors here>] add scareCat`

Or you can spawn it with the tag:

`/summon ocelot ~ ~ ~ {Tags:[scareCat]}`

Then you can only select the ocelot with that tag (and in this example also only select a player with the "holdsItem" tag):

`/execute @p[tag=holdsItem] ~ ~ ~ teleport @e[type=ocelot,tag=scareCat] ~ ~2 ~`

This way you don't become a cat magnet for the whole world while this effect is active, but you get the creeper scariness.

(Another way to not let the ocelot push you would be to add it and you to the same team and then turn collision inside teams off, but that possibly interferes with much more things than this solution.)

Comment: This doesn't work I keep trying and it teleports the ocelot above the command block

Comment: Because you said you had most things done already, I thought you also had the execute command. You have to execute this from the player that should get the ocelot above its head, so for example /execute @p ~ ~ ~ teleport @e[type=ocelot,tag=scareCat] ~ ~2 ~     But of course you enter your own selector instead of @p. I'll edit the answer.